# How to join 2 routers in DRF. Not extend, join

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to join 2 routers like that

I got router that generates `/course/<course_id>`

i got router that generates `/lesson/<lesson_id>`

i need to combine this two urls to `/course/<course_id>/lesson/<lesson_id>`

this is what i tried

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'courses', CourseViewSet)

lesson_router = routers.SimpleRouter()
lesson_router.register('courses/<int:id>/lessons', LessonViewSet)
```

it does't work correctly. It works but only if the url is `/courses/<int:id>/lesson/1`
where `<int:id>` is string not mock

Comment: You can a join 2 routers with ```urlpatterns = router.urls + lesson_router.urls```

Comment: @NikitaZhuikov I'll try it tomorow. Tnx

Comment: @NikitaZhuikov Tnx a lot. This works for me.